# Diferenças na criação dinâmica de um objeto

Tags: delphi, orientação-a-objetos, delphi-7, parâmetros

Quando crio um objeto dinamicamente, por exemplo um formulário, faço desta forma:

```
Formulario := TFormulario.Create(nil);  
try  
    Formulario.ShowModal;  
finally  
    Formulario.Free;  
end;
```

Qual a diferença em criar um objeto passando os seguintes valores para o parâmetro **AOwner** no método **Create**?

```
Formulario := TFormulario.Create(Application);  
Formulario := TFormulario.Create(nil);  
Formulario := TFormulario.Create(Self);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A diferença é quem é o "dono" da janela. Ou seja, se o "dono" for desalocado, todos os *forms* que possuem este *form* como dono também são desalocados.

- No primeiro exemplo, o *form* só é desalocado se a aplicação inteira também for. Este não é muito recomendado por problemas de desempenho, porque as notificações passadas para `Application` demoram um tempo maior para serem processadas;
- No segundo, o *form* não possui dono, ou seja, o programador deve controlar a desalocação deste *form*;
- No terceiro, o *form* pertence à tela que o chamou. Recomendado para modais da tela chamadora.

Comment: Não me lembro de ter lido que utilizar `Application` influencie no desempenho. Possui fonte sobre isso?

Comment: @EMBarbosa Fonte: http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2005/qt/nilselfapp.htm

Comment: Obrigado. Acho que deveria citar as fontes na resposta. +1